# Как перенастроить поведение xml сериализатора

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

У меня вот такая xsd схема:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="mainElement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="testElement1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="testElement1" type="xs:int" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="testElement2" type="xs:boolean" fixed="true" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Результат работы xsd.exe:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class mainElement
{

    #region Private fields
    private object _item;
    #endregion

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("testElement1", typeof(mainElementTestElement1), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("testElement2", typeof(bool), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this._item;
        }
        set
        {
            this._item = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class mainElementTestElement1
{

    #region Private fields
    private int[] _testElement1;
    #endregion

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("testElement1", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public int[] testElement1
    {
        get
        {
            return this._testElement1;
        }
        set
        {
            this._testElement1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

После выполнения вот такого кода:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mainElement));
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"..\..\SerializedData.xml");
var element1Warpper = new mainElementTestElement1 { testElement1 = new int[20] };
var mainElement = new mainElement { Item = element1Warpper };
serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, mainElement);
xmlWriter.Close();
```

я получаю такую xml:

```
<mainElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <testElement1>
    <testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1>
    <testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1>
    <testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1>
    <testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1>
    <testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1>
    <testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1>
    <testElement1>0</testElement1><testElement1>0</testElement1>
  </testElement1>
</mainElement>
```

Мне надо что бы в результате не было верхнего элемента testElement1, а сразу внутри mainElement шел набор элементов.

**UPD**

1. Булево значение может устанавливаться вместо списка int.
2. Мне нужно заполнить данные по xsd схеме, полученной от нашего правительства. В последней редакции там закралась ошибка, которую придется обходить.

   ```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="mainElement">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="testElement1" type="xs:int" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="testElement2" type="xs:boolean" fixed="true" />
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
   ```

Ни один из испробованных мною преобразователей xsd в cs не обрабатывает атрибут `maxOccurs="unbounded"` у элемента внутри `choise`. На выходе я вижу просто описание элемента без какого-либо упоминания, что их может быть много. Т.к. делать полноценный парсер xsd с созданием cs файлов задача долгая и на нее времени нет, то я стараюсь сделать костыль, для которого потребуется изменить поведение сериализатора.

Comment: Покажите как и что вы сериализуете

Comment: Ну вы класс-то покажите, который сериализуете `mainElement`

Comment: Полагаю, `XmlSerializer` можно перенастроить так, чтобы он выдавал желаемый результат. Вот только в итоге результат перестанет соответствовать схеме. В xsd ясно указано, что внутри `mainElement` должен быть или `testElement1` (с массивом внутри), или `testElement2` (булевый).

Comment: А мне и не нужно что-бы он соответсвовал этой схеме.

Comment: Ну а булево значение может присваиваться `Item`? Или это тоже не нужно? Корректная десериализация обоих случаев нужна?

Comment: Жуть какая. Расскажите свою реальную задачу. Если вам нужно просто получать правильный xml на выходе, то напишите правильный класс, который будете сериализовать, расставьте правильные атрибуты. Никакие схемы при этом не нужны будут

Comment: Просто исправьте схему и все.

Comment: Схема получена от правительства и мне надо обратно отправлять данные валидные их схеме. Но работать с их схемой не выйдет.

Comment: @Nodon Вы можете сделать более слабую схему, которая будет совместима с полученной.

Answer (score 2):

Почему просто не составить простой класс, наподобие такого:

```
[XmlRoot("mainElement")]
public class MainElement
{
    [XmlElement("testElement1")]
    public List<int> TestElement1s { get; } = new List<int>();
    [XmlElement("testElement2")]
    public bool? TestElement2 { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeTestElement1s() => !TestElement2.HasValue;
    public bool ShouldSerializeTestElement2() => TestElement2.HasValue;
}
```

`XmlSeralizer` поддерживает методы `ShouldSerialize{Name}`, где `Name` - имя поля или свойства. Этот метод должен возвращать `bool`-значение, которое скажет сериализатору нужно ли сериализовать конкретное поле/свойство

Пример использования:

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainElement));
    var mainElement = new MainElement();
    mainElement.TestElement1s.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 20));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, mainElement);
    string s = writer.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Нет указания, что это choise, а не два разных элемента. И надо ручками править все кривые места в сгенерированном cs файле.

Comment: Да вам это и не нужно, вы уже на своей стороне контролируйте, чтоб у вас было либо то, либо то

Comment: А как я далее узнаю, что тут choise, а не сложный элемент из двух пунктов?

Comment: Далее - это где? Вы можете написать еще один класс, который будет содержать хоть `enum`, хоть каким-то другим образом поддерживать "переключение" и у этого класса будет метод для генерации экземпляра `MainElement`. Везде в своем коде вы будете работать с этим своим классом, а при необходимости передачи документа просто вызываете на нем `GenerateMainElement` и передаете уже его

Comment: @Nodon, дополнил еще

Comment: Там общая структура кода идет такой. Сгенерированные классы обрабатываются через рефлексию для создания GUI и по этим же классам потом идет сериализация. Встроить предложенный тобой вариант будет кажись сложно. Если никто не посоветует, как изменить поведение самого сериализатора, то придется уже править логику.

Comment: @Nodon, фишка в том, что в подавляющем большинстве случаем всевозможные классы, предназначенные для сериализации очень не удобны (не просто так они имеют спец. название DTO и не должны содержать логики) и всегда приходится помимо них иметь нормальные классы, с которыми удобно работать, отображать в GUI и т.д. Ну и есть всевозможные мапперы (см. Automapper), для упрощения преобразований между этими классами

Comment: @Nodon простите, но как вы себе представляете "указание на то что это choise"? В .NET такого типа данных нету и не будет.

Comment: @Nodon если же вам нужен такой класс чтобы GUI по нему сгенерировался нужный - то и задавайте вопрос про генерацию GUI, а не про xsd. Почему мы должны догадываться что у вас еще и GUI какой-то есть?